# android localized String resource with non-translatable word inside

Tags: android, localization

Lets make string resource:

`<string name="pin_code_title">Please enter PIN code</string>`

or

`<string name="enter_btc_tokens_amount">Enter amount of BTC tokens you want to send</string>`

I use [google translation service](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844778?hl=en-GB) where I upload strings.xml to translate it automatically. And I want google to keep "PIN" and "BTC" [and some other brand names]  untranslatable. And this is my problem. Google translates the whole string if it can.

I have checked [android string resources docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource)

Solutions I see and still don't like:

1. To declare parameters:
   `<string name="pin_code_title">Please enter %s</string>` or
   `<string name="enter_btc_tokens_amount">Enter amount of %s you want to send</string>` and then call `textView.text=...`  from Kotlin.
   -I don't like it because I use string resources in layouts.
2. To use "Entities in XML" [described here](https://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/android-strings-xml-tips-tricks). I see comment "xml entities are not supported by translation services" comments and I **hope** that google translates xml files but keeps Entity untranslated.

What is the best practice to keep some words untranslated inside translatable string ?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [LikeTheSalad](https://github.com/LikeTheSalad/android-stem) gradle plugin.

We use it in production for a while without any issues.

An easy and intuitive way to use resource A as nested resource inside resource B.

I tweaked the example of the repo description for you purpose:

```
<resources>
    <string name="pin" translatable="false">PIN</string>
    <string name="pin_code_title">Please enter ${pin} code</string>
</resources>
```

This way, Google will translate `Please enter ${pin} code` (I believe they won't translate `${pin}`), but in the final APK, the resource will be generated correctly: `Please enter PIN code`.

Comment: after few experiments I can say, that google translates words inside ${....}. but not always.

Comment: Bahhh. Well at least I tried. I wonder what Google have to say about it.

Comment: They translated ${now}, but we can use something like ${now_constant}. 
Lucky for us, build fails with undeclared name in ${...}